# Showing that $[x \cdot r, x \cdot r] = x \cdot [[r,r]]$.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a simply connected Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and $r \in \bigwedge^2 \mathfrak{g}$. For $x \in G$ let $\lambda_x$ denote the left multiplication by $x$. Let $[\cdot, \cdot]$ denote the Schouten bracket for multivector fields. Then show that $$\left [\left ( d_e \lambda_x \right )^{\otimes 2} (r), \left (d_e \lambda_x \right )^{\otimes 2} (r) \right ] = \left (d_e \lambda_x \right )^{\otimes 3} \left ([[r,r]] \right )$$ where $[[r,r]] = \left [r_{12}, r_{13} \right ] + \left [r_{12}, r_{23} \right ] + \left [r_{13}, r_{23} \right ]$, i.e., if $r = \sum_i x_i \otimes y_i$, then $$[[r,r]] = \sum_{i,j} [x_i, x_j] \otimes y_i \otimes y_j + \sum_{i,j} x_i \otimes [y_i, x_j] \otimes y_j + \sum_{i,j} x_i \otimes x_j \otimes [y_i, y_j] \,.$$

This amounts to say that the left action respects the Schouten bracket. Could anyone give some suggestion or insight as to how to come up with this equality?

Thanks for your time.

**Source** $:$ Etingof lecture notes on CQG (Alternative approach to Theorem $3.1$ in page no. $28$).